# Word for things that exist in a left and a right version

Tags: word-choice

There's a class of things that come in a right and left form. I mean entities both artificial entities like shoes and also natural like our index fingers.

What's the best English word to describe this class of things?

Comment: They are things that have mirror-image parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might look at *chirality* (adj: *chiral*):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality):

> Chirality /kaɪˈrælɪtiː/ is a property of asymmetry important in several branches of science. The word chirality is derived from the Greek χειρ (kheir), "hand", a familiar chiral object.
> An object or a system is chiral if it is distinguishable from its mirror image; that is, it cannot be superimposed onto it. Conversely, a mirror image of an achiral object, such as a sphere, cannot be distinguished from the object. A chiral object and its mirror image are called enantiomorphs (Greek, "opposite forms") or, when referring to molecules, enantiomers. A non-chiral object is called achiral (sometimes also amphichiral) and can be superposed on its mirror image.

This term shades toward science, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't apply to appendages like hands and feet. In fact, the term comes from the Greek word for *hand*.

> **chirality** *n*
> The aspect of a structure or property, such as the configuration of a molecule or the spin of a particle, that renders that structure or property distinguishable from its mirror image or symmetrical opposite. Also called *handedness*.
> <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chirality)</sub>

Comment: I would immediately have answered "enantiomorphs", and not mentioned chirality at all.

Comment: @ColinFine — Enantiomer (or enantiomorph) is the concrete noun for the entity, chiral is the adjective, which I think the question is requesting. I would amend this answer to stress chiral, rather than the abstract chirality, but my reputation is less robust.

Comment: Chirality and Chiral are pre-eminent suggestions. It is worth mentioning polarity (noun) and bipolar (adjective) for use in some circumstances.

Comment: Chirality is a property of a single thing.  There doesn't need to be any antiomorphs for something to be chiral.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is "[mated items](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mated%20items&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmated%20items%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmated%20items%3B%2Cc0)," though that would apply more towards shoes, socks, mittens, gloves, and the like. You might hear someone tell you to keep "mated items" together when doing laundry, for example. If you have, say, a right mitten, the left one that goes with it would be called its "mate" and vice versa, the same being true for socks, shoes, roller skates, and all sorts of stuff. "Mated items" wouldn't apply to index fingers or various other stuff, though, like left-handed and right-handed scissors, for example, because while there are right-handed and left-handed versions, they don't actually go together, aren't, as a rule, used together or in combination with one another, not like "mated items" are.

I'm not sure there actually is a catch-all term for referring to everything that has a right-handed and a left-handed version. There very well may not be one.